# Delphi: how to create quickly embedded DataSource

Tags: delphi, datasource

I just want to show what's possible with TDBCtrlGrid and I'd like to create as fast as possible 4 records and the TDBCtrlGrid should access those 4 records, to draw custom stuff 4 times.

How whould you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution which can be used with TAdodataset or TClientDataset id adding fields per `FieldDefs.Add` and Create/Open the dataset with `CreateDataSet`.

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  ADODataSet.FieldDefs.Add('ID', ftInteger);
  ADODataSet.FieldDefs.Add('Text', ftString, 50);
  ADODataSet.CreateDataSet;
  for i := 1 to 4 do
  begin
    ADODataSet.Append;
    ADODataSet.Fields[0].Value := 1;
    ADODataSet.Fields[1].Value := Format('Text %d', [i]);
    ADODataSet.Post;
  end;
end;
```

Another solution could be loading data from a resource stream, created from a before designed and filled dataset, saved as XML.

Comment: "saved as XML" implies accessing disk. I just want it to be temporary and all in RAM. Thank you for your answer. As for the ADODataSet, shall I destroy it, or will it be destroyed by Delphi itself (kind of garbage collector that frees everything when the program terminates)?

Comment: If created with Owner or in the IDE it will be freed automatically.

Comment: Saved as XML was meant as, you allready have a complete filled Dataset from a database in another progarm and want to it in your demo without database, you can save it to file, create a resource embeded in your demo and load the recordset directly from the resource. [Send Dataset to a stream end load into a new Dataset from stream](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=85209)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Everything works fine now, but I'm having another problem, I hesitate to ask here or in a new question. I'm using a `DBCtrlGrid` and in the `OnPaintPanel` event I draw what's needed. The problem is that the `DBCtrlGrid` seems to allow to go **beyond** the last record, so I get a `ADODataSet.RecNo < 0`. In the `OnPaintPanel` event I'm trying to do ASAP the `if FADODataSet.RecNo<0 then Exit` but what I get sounds like a bug: when I go beyong the lastest record, `DBCtrlGrid`  paints all the panels with the `ADODataSet.RecNo = -1`. Any idea where I should look?

Comment: More information: to go behind the last record, I have to press the `arrow down` key or click on the "down arrow" in the `DBCtrlGrid`.

Comment: I can send you the `.pas` and `.dfm` files if you want, because I'm totally stuck. So strange behavior.

Comment: @OlivierPons I do not want to be unkind, but this is not the way SO works. -1 in State dsInsert is the usual behavior. If you don't want to enable automatic appends, you can set the property AllowInsert to false or add `procedure TForm1.ADODataSet1BeforeInsert(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
   Abort;
end;`. If this comment won't help you, you should consider to open a new question. regards bummi.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so used to create manually Objects that I didn't look closely enough for those properties. My deep apologize, and thank you for your answer.

Comment: No need for apologize ;-)